# Firestore : Error loading documents. How to resolve error?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My application under ionic angular has been in production for several years, it suddenly stopped working and I get this error on firestore.

I can't add any document manually anymore. The other services (storage / authentication) work.

I should point out that this is not a device or browser error, I have already tried to change it. Moreover, the application no longer works, so it's not just a display bug.

I am on a "Pay as you go" plan with firebase. I have set a limit of 50€ which is far from being reached (0.14€ used)

The number of reads exceeded the 50k free limit yesterday (64k) but it shouldn't be a problem, besides everything was working fine this morning. It has not been exceeded today.

I have sent a message to firebase support. I am waiting for them to respond.

Do you know how I can solve this problem please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Response:

> Right now we're experiencing issues in which users may be unable to
> access their database or see their collections in the Firebase
> Console. We are already investigating further and working to solve it.
> An apology for the inconvenience.
>
> Regards,

The bug is tracked here : https://status.cloud.google.com/incidents/fmEL9i2fArADKawkZAa2 and seems bo te related to europe-west2